# have two variable list and hoping to work on some calculation of the two list

Tags: python, pandas

I am hoping to create few new columns for 'data'.
The first created col is a/d, second b/e, and third c/f.

col1 is a list of names for the original columns
The output of df should look like this

```
a  b  c  d  e  f  res_a  res_c  res_e
1  2  3  4  2  3  0.5    0.75   2/3
```

res_a is a divide b a = 1, b = 2, therefore res_a = 1/2 = 0.5
c/d c = 3, d= 4 res_c = 3/4 = 0.75

my code looks like this now, but I can't get a/b, c/d, and e/f

```
col1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
col2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
for col in cols2:
    data[f'res_{col}'] = np.round(data[col1]/ data[col2],decimals=2)
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic. `a/b` is from `col1`, `e/f` is from `col2`, and `c/d` is from both lists.

Comment: What is `cols2`?

Comment: Where is `res_` in your desired output?

Comment: just responded with edits

Comment: I still don't understand the logic of which columns are divided based on the contents of `col1` and `col2`. Why isn't it `a/d`, `b/e` and `c/f`?

Comment: can you show what data.head() looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip()` to loop over two lists in parallel.

```
cols1 = ['a', 'c', 'e']
cols2 = ['b', 'd', 'f']
for c1, c2 in zip(cols1, cols2):
    data[f'res_{c1}'] = np.round(data[c1] / data[c2], decimals=2)
```

Comment: I might have more columns than this. c1 has 25, c2 has 25. Is there a more efficient way than zip

Comment: Just put them in variables. It's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `pandas.IndexSlice` to pick up alternate columns with a list slicing type of syntax

```py
cix = pd.IndexSlice
df[['res_a', 'res_c', 'res_e']] = np.divide(df.loc[:, cix['a'::2]], df.loc[:, cix['b'::2]])
print(df)

#    a  b  c  d  e  f  res_a  res_c     res_e
# 0  1  2  3  4  2  3    0.5   0.75  0.666667
```

You can read more about the pandas slicers [in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers)

Comment: cix['a'::2], what does this part means in here

Comment: Could we use col1, and col2 here? The reason is that besides a, b, c, I actually have more columns and they are not in order. This is why I set up col1 and col2. col1 has 25 vars, and col2 has 25. Could we fix this

Comment: It means start from column `a` and then get every other column name in the df. @codelearner0504